# When radio button is clicked pass it's value into vue component instance

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components

I have a form in laravel view, in which a have a vue component instance called "tree-select" which does some ajax and generates a dropdown.
In the same form I have a radio button.

What I would like to happen is: when the radio button is clicked, I would like to send the radio button value into the tree-select component instance where the vue instance method would filter the ajax results by using the radio button's value.

Below is snippet of the view code I currently have. Any suggestions on how to have the component instance listen for the radio button click and get it's value?

````
<div class="form-group">
    <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="previous">Previous</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <tree-select name="property_ids" action="/treeSelect"></tree-select>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach here is to store the result of the radio button click/value in your Vuex store. You dispatch an action when the radio button changes, which updates the store to reflect the value that you have set. The second component should use a computed property to read your state from the store and update accordingly.